# Is there any possibility to monitor clipboard change in windows service?

Tags: c#, winapi, clipboard

Currently, I want to create simple c# program to detect clipboard changes and copy text from it.
Everything goes well, but when I open the program by windows service, It does not work anymore.
I know the reason why, but I should find out the way to solve this issue.
Please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: There is no reason why a Windows service would be able to access the clipboard.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/422943/how-to-access-clipboard-in-windows-service
Could you please have a look solution 2 and give me answer?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Is this an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: *"I know the reason why"* - If you actually do, then you can trivially deduce that the problem you are trying to solve doesn't have a solution. You'll need to change the problem statement to make any forward progress.

Comment: If you want to spy on the user, then run your process which spies on the user in the user session

Comment: The clipboard is tied to a user session/desktop. A service runs in a different session than user sessions. Thus, a service cannot access a user's clipboard.  You will have to run a separate process in the user session that monitors the user's clipboard and then sends the data to the server via an IPC mechanism of your choosing.

Comment: Thanks to Remy and David, but not Jabber